# jest-codemods Errors Out Due to Experimental Syntax

Tags: express, jestjs, babeljs

I'm attempting to replace a legacy projects AVA unit tests with Jest. When I run npx jest-codemods on my existing express / @apollo/server project I'm getting this error:

**Transformation error (This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): "importAttributes", "importAssertions".**

The project is using Babel and our config lives in the package.json and looks like this

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "@ava/stage-4"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions"
  ]
},
```

I've added the requested dependency but it's unable to parse files that look like this

```
import sample from '../sample.json' assert { type: 'json' };
```

I've tried creating a separate .babelrc file but it doesn't seem to pick up that this plugin is installed and available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around this issue by importing json files a different way

```
// esm import of json not working without experimental assert
import { createRequire } from 'module';

const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const data = require('./sample.json');
```